# CakePHP Routing - URL With Parameters Only

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two function "product" and "view" in cakephp. If any one type domainname.com/item1 then call "product" function and if domainname.com/item1/item2 then call "view"  function .

item1 and item2 is dynamic content.

```
Router::connect('/:category', array('controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'product'));

Router::connect('/:category/:title', array('controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'view'));
```

I use this code in routes.php

Problem is this if I enter domainname.com/item1 then it is call view function.

please suggest me how to use url rewriting in cakephp .

Comment: How does Your product action looks?

Comment: What is you controller name?

Comment: My controller is Post.

Comment: `Problem is this if I enter domainname.com/item1 then it is call view function.` - are you sure about that? The above routes do not match that behavior (demonstrate it).

Answer (score 1):

try to add /posts and specifie the order like this:

```
    Router::connect('/posts/:category/:title', 
            array('controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'view'),
            array(
            // order matters since this will simply map ":category" to $category in your action
            'pass' => array('category', 'title')
            )
            );
```

You can take a look to the doc http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/development/routing.html

Comment: we do not put any prefix in url like "posts"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Router::connect('/:category/:product', 
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'), 
    array('pass' => 
        array('product')
));

Router::connect('/:product', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'product'));
```

Comment: Same problem is there. At a time only one router are  work .

Comment: What do you mean? This does what you have asked. If you go to item1 domainname.com/item1 otherwise if you go to item1/item2 goes to domainname.com/item1/item2

Comment: What is you controller name?

Comment: item1 and  item2 is dynamic content
if i enter domainname.com/asus-zenfone-2 it goes to product page and if domainname.com/mobile/samsung  it goes view page

Comment: in this mobile is fix but somr time it is mobile or tab-late or somthing else .it is dynamic content

Comment: You didn't say that. Any way now check